# Declare a case object literal as its parent type?

Tags: scala

I have a singleton `Banana` class and want to avoid postfixing `.type` to all it's usages, so I've defined it like so:

```
sealed trait Banana
case object Banana extends Banana
```

Now I can have clean method signatures like `def peel(foo: String): Banana`

One minor annoyance though - it's kind of hard for me to reference the *case object* `Banana` while wanting it to actually be the parent type. Observe:

```
scala> sealed trait Banana; case object Banana extends Banana
trait Banana
object Banana

scala> Banana
val res0: Banana.type = Banana

scala> val banana: Banana = Banana
val banana: Banana = Banana
```

Now in the above, `res0` is of type `Banana.type`, which is not the type I'm looking for! `banana` on the other hand, is indeed the type I want. Is it possible to get a banana *literal* of the *latter* type without first assigning it to a value?

Obviously `Banana.asInstanceOf[Banana]` works, but skirts around the whole pesky "compile time safety" thing.

Comment: `Banana.type` is a subtype of `Banana` so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Not so - I'm handling these types inside an `EitherT` which is not covariant in for comprehensions, so giving it a `Banana.type` when it's expecting a `Banana` is a compile error. :/

Comment: You have `widen` for that, you can also do a simple upcast at use site.

Comment: I'd prefer to just straight up give the `EitherT` the proper type in the first place rather then widening it later on, but what do you mean by "a simple upcast"?

Comment: `EitherT.leftT[F, A](Banana : Banana)` or, maybe if the return type is explicit the compiler will be able to do the upcast for you _(not sure about that one)_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realize that this works:

```
type Banana = Banana.type
object Banana {
  // ...
}
```

Much better to just *not* use your hack in the first place.

If you do use the hack, note that `expr: Type` is an expression (it is called a type ascription):

```
sealed trait Banana; case object Banana extends Banana
def f[T](x: T)(implicit eq: T =:= Banana): T = x
// f(Banana) // tries to call with T = Banana.type, fails
f(Banana: Banana) // calls f with the right T = Banana instead of T = Banana.type
```

Comment: Ah, it was the `Banana: Banana` that I needed! I did indeed forget that that is in fact it's own expression. I'll have to try out the type alias though, it seems like it might allow me to eliminate this kind of type massaging in the first place.

Comment: Indeed the type alias solves it even better! Thanks so much @HTNW.